# How to convert a text file to image file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I converted a CSV file (which has numerical data) to a grayscale image.

When I tried to display the image, it's showing nothing. It displays only the x-axis and y-axis. But I want each and every row to be converted to an image.

So, I converted the CSV file to TXT file.

I am trying to convert this text file which contains some numbers delimited by a space to an image file. I want to build a CNN model in Keras using Conv2D.

**Can anyone please give me some insights on how can I do this?**

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your code that doesn't work

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np

image = 'Monday_X.png'
gray_img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np

image = 'Monday_X.png'
gray_img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) it's giving a shape of 52991, 78. Likewise I have Monday_Y.png which has a shape of 52991, 2. These two are the training sets. I have similar ones with different shape i.e. 44591, 78 and 44591, 2 for testing. In order to pass input shape for Conv2D I reshaped it to (1,1,52991,78) (channels_first). But while training the model it's giving me error like this:   ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 52991 target samples.